# Android Studio seems to build old version of project

Tags: android, android-studio, onclick

I am wondering if this is some bug in Android Studio or I am simply lack od knowladge but straight to the point.
I am writing simple client-server via bluetooth app on android. At some point I encoured following problem:

```
07-11 18:59:20.553  10364-10364/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method parujUrzadzenia(View) in the activity class com.example.pc.klient_serwerbluetooth.Klient for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button6'
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3775)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18190)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: parujUrzadzenia [class android.view.View]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3768)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18190)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 19:34:00.498      449-522/? E/ActivityManager﹕ The package com.example.pc.klient_serwerbluetooth is not found. Failure starting process com.example.pc.klient_serwerbluetooth
```

For what I understand Android Studio can't find method parujUrzadzenia(View) that is marked in button6's properties as onClick method...the funny thing is i deleted this button in my way of solving this problem.

I can't post picture of my project due to low reputation but like I said. I've deleted the reference to method from .xml and method from .java file and got an error saying that there is no required onClick method. So I deleted this whole button and still got this error.

Any advices will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: cleaning and rebuilding the project can be a solution

Comment: Uninstall previous build before installing the new build.

Comment: Looks like it is, i changed the name of my module and cleaned solution and rebuild it, surprisingly now there is no such error in debbuger. Thats the way to build your IDK. I wasn't installing my modules, just debugging them throu IDK.